# Delta-Epsilon, find delta?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find a number $\delta$ such that if $|x-2|<\delta$ then $|4x-8|<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon=0.1$

Are the steps mentioned below correct?

Step 1: Simplified the expression,
$ 4|x-2|<\epsilon ==> |x-2|<\epsilon/4===> \epsilon=\delta/4 ==> \delta=0.1/4=0.025$

Is this the correct method to approach this problem?

Answer (score 3):

For any $\varepsilon$, you can choose any $\delta\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$.
so when $|x-2|<\delta$, then $|4x-8|<4\delta<\varepsilon$

Answer (score 2):

I think it is solved correct, but also all range of numbers are good not only $\varepsilon$.
$\delta \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{4}$ or $\delta \leq 0.025$.

Comment: Actually the value for $\epsilon$ is given in the question as well.

Comment: It is, and i typed and the end "δ≤0.025"